# how to grey out php contact form after submit?

Tags: contact-form

I have a PHP contact form, with a simple submit button. What i want to do is once the user has clicked submit, add a function which greys out all text boxes within the form.

Or the form disappears altogether so i can place a label on the page to say its been completed. Is there anyway to go about this without the use of javascript or jquery?

Currently the code for the submit button is:

```
<input type="submit" value=" Continue " style="width:200px;height:40px">
```

which uses the PHP post method.

Comment: The only problem i see with adding an iframe would be if the button is outside of the frame, it would not be possible to submit the form. And if the submit button was inside the form, the iframe cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon submission, the values should be posted to the PHP script. You can then implement a method of checking if the user's value has been accepted.

At the top of your code, implement the method that is being used to save the input:

```
<?php
     $form_submit_success = false;
     //Your input processing code here.
     $form_submit_success = true; //Set this variable to true if form data was accepted.

     if($form_submit_success) {
         //Message to inform the user that form submission was a success.
     } else {
?>
<!-- HTML Form Code here -->
<?php
     }
?>
```

Comment: I should have been a bit more clear, what im after is not a temporary success/completed page, but if the user returns to the form it will be marked as completed. I'm guessing ths would involve the use of cookies?

Comment: This would require some form of cookies or IP based tracking. However, there are trade-offs to each of the approaches.

You could insert the information into a MySQL database with the IP address of somebody that has already submitted a form. However, IPs do not necessarily mean users (especially in settings such as schools where large bodies of students share one IP address).

Cookies also have their drawbacks because a different browser can affect the status of the form. However, cookies would be the cleanest approach for your problem.